# TimeoutException, TaskCanceledException C#

Tags: c#, exception, timeoutexception

I am new to C# and I find exceptions a bit confusing...
I have a web app with the following code:

```
try
{
    //do something
}
catch (TimeoutException t)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException tc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tc);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

When I debug the code, it throws the e `Exception`, the most general one and when I hover over the exception info it turns out that it's the `TaskCanceledException`. Why isnt the `TaskCanceledException` caught? If the exception was a `TimeoutException` would it catch the `TimeoutException` or would it also catch the `Exception`? Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't an `AggregationException` thrown from a `Task` object? show us the throwing call

Comment: ...yes, it's the System.AggregateException and the InnerException is the System.Threading.Task.TaskCanceledException.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When catching an `Exception`, you have to make sure it is **exactly** the exception being thrown. When using `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.Startnew` and generally involving an exception being thrown from a `Task` (unless the task is being awaited with the [`await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) keyword), the outer exception you're dealing with is an [`AggregateException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx), because a `Task` unit may have child tasks which may also throw exceptions.

From [Exception Handling (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Unhandled exceptions that are thrown by user code that is running
>   inside a task are propagated back to the joining thread, except in
>   certain scenarios that are described later in this topic. Exceptions
>   are propagated when you use one of the static or instance Task.Wait or
>   Task.Wait methods, and you handle them by enclosing the call
>   in a try-catch statement. If a task is the parent of attached child
>   tasks, or if you are waiting on multiple tasks, then multiple
>   exceptions could be thrown. To propagate all the exceptions back to
>   the calling thread, the Task infrastructure wraps them in an
>   AggregateException instance. The AggregateException has an
>   InnerExceptions property that can be enumerated to examine all the
>   original exceptions that were thrown, and handle (or not handle) each
>   one individually. Even if only one exception is thrown, it is still
>   wrapped in an AggregateException.

So, in order to deal with that, you have to catch `AggregateException`:

```
try
{
    //do something
}
catch (TimeoutException t)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException tc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tc);
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
   // This may contain multiple exceptions, which you can iterate with a foreach
   foreach (var exception in ae.InnerExceptions)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
   }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: Ok. Now my app should timeout, but instead of a TimeoutException I get this AggregateException with TaskCanceledException inside. How do I get the program to catch the TimeoutException?

Comment: basically is it possible for a TimeoutException to be thrown instead of TaskCanceledException?

Comment: No, it isn't possible. An `AggregateExcception` is thrown from a `Task` because it may also contain children tasks. Its simply a wrapper.